# Can we use $each with insert in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So, I was reading about the `$each` modifier in `mongoDB`, that it is used to `update` multiple elements in an array in a document.

I was wondering if we could do the same while using `insert` - meaning adding multiple array values at once.

For example, I wrote this to insert multiple values in array within a document -

```
 db.movies.insert({"genre":"horror"},
      ...{$push:{"top10":
      ...{"$each":["Nightmare on Elm Street","Saw","Final Destination","Scary Movie","The Exorcist","The Babadook","The Conjuring","Cabin In The World","Sinster","Hush"]
 }}})
```

I see that the Write Result is displayed the document to is also created. However, when doing a `find({})` on the document, this is the only thing that I see is the ObjectId and the `genre` field created in the document.

`db.movies.find({}).pretty()` returns

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("590e1f3173874ca86f6cd6d6"), "genre" : "horror" }
```

Can we use `$each` only when we're updating a document (and not inserting)?

Comment: You can simply use `db.movies.insert({"genre":"horror","top10":["Nightmare on Elm Street","Saw","Final Destination","Scary Movie","The Exorcist","The Babadook","The Conjuring","Cabin In The World","Sinster","Hush"]})` and yes $each is only update modifier.

Comment: Well, I know this can be done this way. I was simply pondering if $each can come into play while inserting values. Seems like it can not

Comment: It is just not applicable here. $each as listed in documentation is update operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/. You can use javascript `Array.push` if you want to add values into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` method in `MongoDB` does not allow for any modifiers, as per the documentation:https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insert/
So, the `$each` modifier can only be used for update as @bad_deadpool rightly pointed out.